# Как сверстать слайдер со слайдами в шахматном порядке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Прошу совета по лучшей организации такого рода слайдера. Больше интересует вопрос верстки (css), с последующей адаптацией. С самим слайдером все вроде бы понятно — как обычно айтемы с отрицательным маргином.
[image: slider chess style]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvvCorkAFbE  мало чем отличается

Comment: тоже похожее https://codepen.io/nickoafan/pen/eJMaBx